# Is there a shortcut to quickly copy a hyperlink link?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to copy a hyperlink but paste it as it's link? at the moment I'm opening the link and copying it from by browser but is there a quicker way??

Comment: Unclear: Where do you copy from?

Comment: Sorry should have said, I meant from Microsoft Word

Comment: How about recording a macro? And add the macro quick access button? Or macro shortcut key?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on it and "Copy hyperlink" or "Copy link destination."